# Vitess on Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, vitess

I'm trying to setup Vitess on a local Kubernetes by following [this](http://vitess.io/getting-started/#start-a-vitess-cluster). After installed vtctld and set up the web UI. I saw following error on TOPOLOGY BROWSER

```
/etcd

Error

Get http://etcd-global:4001/v2/keys/vt/cells?quorum=true&recursive=false&sorted=true: dial tcp: lookup etcd-global on 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems the problem is that there is no DNS setup on Kubernate. After setup DNS, this error gone...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you answered your question. It sounds like you were not running the DNS addon.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/admin/dns.md
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/dns/README.md

Most cloud providers support the DNS addon. Set ENABLE_CLUSTER_DNS to true.